# postgres user cannot access location of new data directory

Tags: permissions, postgresql-9.3, ubuntu

I moved my postgresql 9.3 data directory to a different drive, however, my `postgres` user cannot seem to access that new drive despite my best efforts. I am running on ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64. So I created a new directory under `/media/$USER/kauthama/data/psql` and set postgres:postgres as the owner. However when I try and do `initdb` the directory keeps saying permission denied. Even when I do `su postgres` and then try to navidate to the new directory, the autocompletion stops at `/media/$USER/` and cannot find the drive `kauthama.` I even added `postgres` to the `sudoers` group to see if that would work. The permissions on `kauthama` are basically `$USER` is the owner and the `sudo` group owns it. So the postgres user should have all the permissions needed to navigate to the directory. Any thought on why this is not working?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. So the permissions at one level of the directory hierarchy did not have any setting for letting the `other` group read that level. Thus that blocked the postgres user from being able to see a drive mounted by any other user. Once that was changed with

```
chmod -R 777 /media/$USER
```

Then this created permissions for the `other` group to see the directory. This fixed the issue.